# Is this Incentive Mechanisms survey email legit?

Tags: support, email

Is this official email from StackOverflow? I'm suspecting it's a phishing, but just to be sure.

[image: Survey Email Capture]

Comment: It's not official, since it comes from "surveymonkeyuser.com", not "stackoverflow.email". It does not seem to say it's from Stack Overflow, however...

Comment: I received this as well; I checked the from address, the link to the survey, and determined it was some phishing attempt. I wouldn't bother following the link unless it actually comes from a StackOverflow email.

Comment: The email address points to the National University of Defense Technology in China.  Yikes, that's fairly unsubtle.  Academia is always interested in discovering the SO secret, they don't read each other's papers.  Let's keep it a secret.

Comment: It does not look like "phishing" at all – unless its definition changed or the questions include a "click here to log in to your Stack Overflow account". It seems nothing but a harmless questionnaire, with *maybe* some bad wording that *might* suggest it is *from* Stack Overflow.

Comment: @HansPassant I mean, that's kind of the weird part for me as I received one of these too. It seems kind of weird to me as I looked at the questions and they look like legitimate research questions. And it's kind of weird that they'd send them from the Chinese Military Academy. Like if they got my email from some sort of data breach, it seems weird to send it from the Chinese Military.